# Slow $http.get response for external calls

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have an angularJS app that makes several calls to external REST services.

I noticed these were slow so I did a trace like this:

```
console.time("XHR");
        $http.get(url).success(function(data,status){
            console.timeEnd("XHR");
            callback(data);
        });
```

In my console it logs always around 1000ms however when I trace the actual XHR request in the network tab in Chrome, it shows that the request only took +/-260ms

I don't know if this matters but these calls are done to another domain. 
If I trace the calls done to the same domain $http.get("/api/someCall") than the response times are good. 
I seem to only see the delay when the calls are done to an external domain.

Is there something I need to do to speed this up?

Comment: How long does it take when you enter the URL directly in your browser?

Comment: 200ms. That's why I find it odd to see over 1000ms when I trace it in my app.

Comment: If it's cross domain it's most likely that angular does 2 calls, first one with method `OPTIONS` to check what you can use, and second with the  `GET`

Comment: I can only see a single call in the XHR trace in Chrome. If Angular does 2, wouldn't I see both of them?

Comment: @Passero have you got fix  for same?